# IP Addresses for Google Translation API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip-address, google-translation-api

We're deploying code that consumes the Google Translation API to a very secure area where outbound connections are limited to known IPs.

So far, I've been unable to find where Google lists the blocks of IPs necessary to allow Translation API traffic.

We only have Bronze level support, so the community is all we have to rely on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link [Google IP Address ranges](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en) appears to have what we needed.  It was unclear to me that it actually covered *all* Google EndPoint IPs (rather than just ones that might be a source of an email message).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds impractical to add and allow all those IP ranges in your firewall and still stay very secure. Some of those IPs could be used by Google customers. The article also says "the addresses often change". This means you have to check SPF records frequently for changes and update your firewall rules.

Comment: Yes, it does seem impractical as we found we could access GMail as well as other apps that we'd rather avoid.